# Laravel phpunit "faking" a Request object and an Exception object, is it possible?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, guzzle

I wrote a package for Laravel that has a function that requires two parameters. the first one is an instance of Request that contains a Content-Type and the second one is an instance of Exception (can also be a simple string).

If the Request has an Content-Type of JSON the Exception will be encoded in JSON.

I'm trying to test the package using PHPUnit, but I couldn't figure out how should I do it. I thought of using Guzzle for that but it's seems too much for such a simple test.

Can anyone suggest me what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking#mocking-facades):

> You should not mock the Request facade. Instead, pass the input you desire into the HTTP helper methods such as get and post when running your test.

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering!

I did looked in the docs before answering and saw this note, But I didn't understand how to "pass the input you desire into the HTTP helper methods..", How something like that should look, and how can I pass the Content-Type inside of it?

Comment: @user2561521 in test class use `$this->get()`. Also, you may want to check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/http-tests#customizing-request-headers) out (there's an example).